# Boundary conditions for the wave equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

Consider the wave equation (In this context, I'm talking about an acoustic wave),

$$\frac{\partial^2 p'}{\partial t ^2} - c^{2} \nabla^2 p'=S.$$

Let us assume this is in free-space, i.e, there is no incoming wave. To solve this equation in spherical coordinates, the only boundary condition that is applied is

$$p' \rightarrow 0~~~ \text{as}~~~ r \rightarrow \infty.$$

How is that we are able to solve an equation that is second order in space using only one BC? Is there some sort of symmetry BC applied at $r = 0$ that is implicitly implied in the solution?

Comment: https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat417/spr14/lecture14.pdf

Comment: @Wolphramjonny doesn't help. They don't talk about the equation in spherical coordinates unless I'm missing something.

Comment: right, I missed that

Answer (score 2):

The wave equation is  an *hyberbolic*  partial differential equation. You need *Cauchy Data* (for example, initial value  and time derivative of $p({\bf x},t)$ at time $t_0$) to determine the solution.  Boundary data is what is needed  for elliptic equations such as $\nabla^2\phi=0$. This is true independently of the chosen coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I'll look into Cauchy data as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mikestone, you need two conditions for this problem.

What I suspect is that you are solving for an infinite domain and might obtain solutions that are proportional to $1/r^n$. These terms are unbounded in the origin of the system and their constants are taken as zero for the solution to be physically admissible.

If your domain does not include the origin, then you definitely need another boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks. I was also wondering if its the singularity at $r= 0$ that leads to the second BC.